# Newbie cant get JSON

Tags: mongodb, livecode

In LiveCode I have a stack connecting to a localhost MongoDB, the stack has a button with a mouseup handler and the function JSONToArray from MergJSON and two fields: "A" to receive the server answer "as is" and field B" to receive the decoded JSON.

This is the script of the button:

```
on mouseup
  set the hideConsoleWindows to true
  put shell("C:\\mongodb\bin\mongo.exe --eval" && quote & \ 
    "printjson(db.test.findOne())" & quote) into pJSON
  put pJSON into fld "a"
  put JSONToArray(pJSON) into tArray
  put tArray["a"] into fld "B"
end mouseup
```

The contents of fld "A" after mouseup is:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.7
connecting to: test
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52e3f87c8da8b1efb07004c9"), "a" : 1 }
```

The script fails with the following LiveCode error:

```
        executing at 8:58:32 PM
Type    could not decode JSON: invalid token near 'MongoDB'
Object  Completo
Line    repeat for each line tKey in mergJSONDecode(pJSON,"tArray")
Hint    could not decode JSON: invalid token near 'MongoDB'
```

If I change the script to:

```
on mouseup
  put shell("C:\\mongodb\bin\mongo.exe --eval" && quote & "printjson(db.test.find())" & quote) into pJSON
  put pJSON into fld "A"
end mouseup
```

Field "A" gets this:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.7
connecting to: test
{
    _"_mongo" : connection to 127.0.0.1,
    _"_db" : test,
    _"_collection" : test.test
    _"_ns" : "test.test",
    _"_query" : {
    __
_},
    _"_fields" : null,
    _"_limit" : 0,
    _"_skip" : 0,
    _"_batchSize" : 0,
    _"_options" : 0,
    _"_cursor" : null,
    _"_numReturned" : 0,
    _"_special" : false,
    _"help" : function () {
    print("find() modifiers");
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

I am shortening the actual field "A" content, it has a lot of text.

Can you guide me please? What I am doing wrong? Why I am not getting a JSON. I checked `{ "_id" : ObjectId("52e3f87c8da8b1efb07004c9"), "a" : 1 }` using an online service finding that it is not a valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Try feeding only the string from { until } without the preceding lines.

```
on mouseUp
  set the hideConsoleWindows to true
  put shell("C:\mongodb\bin\mongo.exe --eval" && \
    quote & "printjson(db.test.findOne())" & quote) into pJSON
  put pJSON into fld "a"
  put JSONToArray(line 3 to -1 of pJSON) into tArray // <-- this line changed
  put tArray["a"] into fld "B"
end mouseUp
```

Comment: Yes `.findOne()` would return only one record as something that can be interpreted to JSON, but I cannot say tou are understanding the problem. The point is that `.find()` does not return something that can be serialized as JSON. You seem to have missed the point while focusing on the `livecode` component. (Additionally keep in mind this question looked a lot different many hours ago, but the point is still valid)

Comment: We should probably wait for Javier to comment on our answers.

Comment: Neil, Mark, thank you very much.  I'll try to change the script to: put JSONToArray(line 3 to -1 of pJSON) into tArray , as Mark suggest, Neil, I'll re-read the info.mation about .find to be sure I allways get a JSON.  Please wait for my next post.

Comment: Javier, when you have new results, you can update your question to include those.

Comment: @Mark , Neil Lunn pointed out correctly that I was getting was a cursor not a JSON, his explanation of the way the shell works regarding find() was accurate, I tried db.test.find() and the results are identical when issuing: var c = db.test.find() ; while ( c.hasNext() ) printjson( c.next()).  The thing now is how to code this in LC, I tried: put shell("C:\mongodb\bin\mongo.exe --eval  var c = db.test.find() ; while ( c.hasNext() ) printjson( c.next() )") into pJSON  put pJSON into fld "A" but field "A" gets error MongoDB...
connecting to: c
SyntaxError: missing variable name (shell eval):1

Answer (score -3):

TO answer the question "What am I doing wrong?" you first need to understand what you are doing when you invoke [.find()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) on a collection.

Now as the documentation in that link will tell you (right at the top of the page) you are **not** returning *results* from this call but in fact you are returning a [cursor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-cursor). Now what you may **see** when invoking this is the shell is a series of documents come out.

But the only reason this happens is that the shell (in interactive form) acts as a [**REPL**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) and *evaluates* your statements in order to *print* the output. So the *interactive* shell is evaluating your [cursor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-cursor) and calling a [.next()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.next/) method on that several times. This is **only** a convenience function while working in the shell.

In order to get the results *programmatically* as you intend to do, you need to *do something* with this [cursor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-cursor) to actually see the results. Now you *could* create a loop where you *iterate* over the results calling [.next()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.next/) each time, but for your purposes the [.toArray()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22000015/newbie-cant-get-json) method should suffice.

So in a *slightly expanded* way, for clear definition you would have a script form like this:

```
var cursor = db.test.find();

var results = cursor.toArray();

printjson( results );
```

Or as the general *one liner* using method chaining:

```
printjson( db.test.find().toArray() )
```

And that will emit the JSON *Array* of documents you need.

Alternately you can use the .findOne() method which will just return a single *document* which you can pass in to the `printjson()` function.

Comment: I don't see how this solves the problem. OP doesn't need a result of type array. In LiveCode, everything is a string. The Json result has to be a correctly formatted string, that can be fed to the MergJson external.

Comment: @Mark there is a clear distinction in the answer. The OP is not returning anything that is valid as the result is a cursor <Object> and that I gave them the results (from the printjson() method) as a string.

Comment: HI, I change the line in the mouseuphandler to: put JSONToArray(line 3  to -1 of pJSON) into tArray // <-- this line changed.  But I get the error: Type could not decode JSON: invalid token near 'Sat'
Object Completo
Line repeat for each line tKey in mergJSONDecode(pJSON,"tArray")
Hint could not decode JSON: invalid token near 'Sat'  pJSON still not a valid JSON, I think Neil pointed out that pJSON is a cursor.

Comment: So taking in consideration that what I am getting as result is s cursor, the problem is how to iterate on it using LC commands to build an array to be passed to the function.  Please correct me if I am wrong.